Long pressing Super_Left should show me workspaces
I want to see workspaces when holding Super_Left (The Windows Key).
Can I achieve this in some way?

That functionality is already set in Keyboard > View and Customise shortcuts > System > Show the overview with Super+S.

Feel free to navigate to that option using Settings and change it to whatever key combination you prefer.
On the other hand, if your need is one of accessibility then you can navigate to Settings > Accessibility > Typing Assist and set options there such as Sticky Keys, Slow Keys or Bounce Keys according to your need.

Bunce Keys reference

No, i need to bind it to work with long press.

I've added an option regarding Accessibility.
